# Can somebody show me graphical representation of rails classes hierarchy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner and am confused by the structure of ruby on rails. Everywhere I've found it described in a way that is too complicated for me. I need to understand how model, controller and view interact with each other or how variables ended up in one scope for them.

Comment: Take a look at official guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is pretty good:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the railroad gem to generate a class hierarchy diagram.

```
gem install railroad  
railroad -h
```

http://railroad.rubyforge.org/

Comment: There is also a Rails3 compatible gem is railroady which is based on railroad ( https://github.com/preston/railroady )